# Server services on a farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, server-farm, service, farm

I have installed a SharePoint farm *SP2013 Windows 2012 R2. I have 2 servers, 1 front end and 1 web application. The database is located in another server. I was thinking about what services should be enabled on each server. 
For ex : Business Data Connectivity Service, Central Administration etc etc. At which one of the servers should I enable them an at which one not. I need to have a list with all services and where it is recommended to install them. 
Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

To append to the answer above: the server that hosts Central Administration will be the application server by default. It'll hold all the services - also by default. It's recommended as best practice to have multiple servers that can host Central Administration, so an option is to start the SERVICE "Central Administration" on your web front end, in case the application server with your original CA goes down.

If you are talking about service applications instead, the basic ones that I believe are necessary include Managed Metadata (for navigation!) and Search Service Application (for searching). Any additional service applications are up to your discretion for what your server needs. Hopefully that helps!

Essentially, the web front end should host the web applications and/or application pools only... but if your web applications are light duty, you can move some services (IE hosting CA) onto it....

This is all from experience, though. I have my own testing environment. let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose 1 web application as an 'Application Server'. If yes, then it is capable of running the services as per the requirement you have. It is advised to add only those services which are essential to avoid performance issues. Please refer to this article by Martin for more knowledge: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martinkearn/archive/2008/03/13/useful-facts-about-sharepoint-farms.aspx